# HTML5 game calling super class constructor

Tags: javascript

In the tutorial I'm following, I am creating a spaceship that will inherit from the Actor superclass. When creating the spaceship constructor, I call the Actor constructor using **Actor.call(this, scene, x, y)**

Can anyone tell me the purpose of **Actor.call(this, scene, x, y)** I assume it's a way of cutting repetition as I am able to inherit the Actor's properties (this.scene = scene, this.x = x and this.y = y)?

```
function Actor(scene, x, y) {
    this.scene = scene;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    scene.register(this);
}

Actor.prototype.moveTo = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.scene.draw();
};

Actor.prototype.draw = function() {
    var image = this.scene.images[this.type];
    this.scene.context.drawImage(image, this.x, this.y);
};

function SpaceShip(scene, x, y) {
    **Actor.call(this, scene, x, y); // call actor constructor** 
    this.points = 0;
}
SpaceShip.prototype = Object.create(Actor.prototype)

SpaceShip.prototype.type = "spaceShip";
SpaceShip.prototype.scorePoint = function() {
    this.points++;
};
```

Comment: Is your question simply "what are constructors"?

Comment: My question is - In the Spaceship constructor what is the purpose of  Actor.call(this, scene, x, y)

Comment: do you have any Java (or any similar Object Oriented language) experience? Also, do you know how prototypal inheritance works in javascript?

Comment: @stckpete The purpose is to run the constructor, as you seem to already know. So my question is, do you not understand what constructors are for, or why they're useful?

Comment: @meagar I'm currently learning Javascript and prototypal inheritance. From my understanding constructors are used to 'construct new objects', using the 'new' keyword. I just wanted to confirm if Actor.call is a way to cut code repetition (i.e. its a way of assigning this.x and this.y to the spaceship)

Comment: @stckpete Reducing code repetition is part of it, but it's also about encapsulation: Only `Actor` should have to know how its internal state needs to be setup in order for an instance of `Actor` to begin life in a valid state. Child classes shouldn't have to duplicate the setup logic *or* be updated when the setup logic changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.call()` is a special way to call a function in javascript. Using `call` you can set a different scope for a function (that is, when you use `this` in a function, it will be the one passed as first parameter in `call` rather than the normal scope for that function).

In this case it's very similar to Java's `super()` to call the parent class constructor since it does exactly what the Actor's constructor does but on an instance of the Spaceship class rather than an instance of the Actor's class. So yes, you can say it's used so you don't need to put the same code used inside the Actor constructor inside the Spaceship constructor, although that's an oversimplified way to see it

On the MDN page there's an example on how to use `.call()` to chain constructors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

> Examples Using call to chain constructors for an object
>
> You can use call to chain constructors for an object, similar to Java.
>   In the following example, the constructor for the Product object is
>   defined with two parameters, name and price. Two other functions Food
>   and Toy invoke Product passing this and name and price. Product
>   initializes the properties name and price, both specialized functions
>   define the category.

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0) {
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product ' +
                      this.name + ' with a negative price');
  }
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

function Toy(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'toy';
}

var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
```